# how to load swagger UI, in before_request looking for token but token used in particular endpoint

Tags: flask, swagger, token, basic-authentication, flasgger

#flask, swagger, before_request problem
in app.py one function is decorated with before_request and in this fuction
"""
token = request.args.get('token')
if not token:
return jsonify({
'status': 'error',
'message': 'Unauthorized.'
})

```
    # Parse Token
    token = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(token)
    token = token.decode('utf-8')"""
```

suppose i have some endpoints like /api/employees when i want load swagger UI its unauthrize becauz of before request.
so i want to load ui, and afterthat in parameter token send to get response from endpoints
if you have simliar scenerio please share me support doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case we have to bypass some URLs like '/apidocs', '/', and some HTML, css, jquery related config have to add in swagger config.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():

    if request.path == '/apidocs' or request.path == '/apispec.json':
        return shutdown_session() 
    try:
       # some code here
    except:
       # something here
```

## in swagger config you have add like this

```
swagger_config = {
    "headers": [
    ],
    "specs": [
        {
            "endpoint": 'apispec',
            "route": '/apispec.json',
            "rule_filter": lambda rule: True,  # all in
            "model_filter": lambda tag: True,  # all in
        }
    ],

    "static_url_path": "/flasgger_static",
    "swagger_ui": True,
    "specs_route": "/apidocs",
    'swagger_ui_bundle_js':  '//unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-bundle.js',
    'swagger_ui_standalone_preset_js': '//unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js',
    'jquery_js': '//unpkg.com/jquery@2.2.4/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'swagger_ui_css': '//unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui.css'
}
```